# Propel diff command is not working as expected

Tags: mysql, orm, database-migration, propel

When I use `propel diff` command, it makes a migration but it's not as expected. If I add a new field to the database, it generates a drop migration. So the `up` function contains:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` DROP `field`
```

Why Propel is doing so? Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) There is no question in the post. 2) Even if there were a question, we would not be able to answer it, since you have not shared too much information with us.

Comment: @Shadow For people who are familiar with migration and ORMs, there is a clear question. The generator shouldn't consider change as drop.

Comment: If there is no question, then we can only guess what the question is. Still you have not shared enough information with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found there were a problem in how I was using Propel. I should first change `schema.xml` file then call `propel diff` command.